# How is Environment bean added in the Spring container?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm learning about Spring MVC and Hibernate with Java configuration and I have this code:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.dgs.springdemo")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"classpath:persistence-mysql.properties"})
public class WebAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {

        // create view resolver
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        // set properties on view resolver
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource myDataSource() {

        // create connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // set the jdbc driver
        try {
            myDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");       
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }

        // for sanity's sake, let's log url and user ... just to make sure we are reading the data
        logger.info("jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info("jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));

        // set database connection props
        myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        // set connection pool props
        myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize")));
        myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize")));
        myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize")));      
        myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime")));

        return myDataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

        return props;               
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){

        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        // set the properties
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        // setup transaction manager based on session factory
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

}
```

I see that the Environment bean is injected in this class. And I want to know how is this bean added in the Spring container? Who added it?

This is the pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dgs</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVCHibernateXML</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>SpringMVCHibernateXML Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>8.0.12</mysql.connector.version>
        <c3po.version>0.9.5.2</c3po.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring MVC support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
          <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet, JSP and JSTL support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- C3PO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3po.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVCHibernateXML</finalName>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- Add Maven coordinates (GAV) for: maven-war-plugin -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Also I don't understand why I cannot see this Evironment bean in the Spring container?

Here are all the beans from Spring container, and I cannot see the Environment bean:

```
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor : class org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor : class org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor
org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory : class org.springframework.context.event.DefaultEventListenerFactory
webAppConfig : class com.dgs.springdemo.config.WebAppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1e6ba9c
customerController : class com.dgs.springdemo.controller.CustomerController
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration : class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f4728e5
requestMappingHandlerMapping : class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
mvcPathMatcher : class org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher
mvcUrlPathHelper : class org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper
mvcContentNegotiationManager : class org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
viewControllerHandlerMapping : class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping
beanNameHandlerMapping : class org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping
resourceHandlerMapping : class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping
mvcResourceUrlProvider : class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlProvider
defaultServletHandlerMapping : class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$EmptyHandlerMapping
requestMappingHandlerAdapter : class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
mvcConversionService : class org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService
mvcValidator : class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport$NoOpValidator
mvcUriComponentsContributor : class org.springframework.web.method.support.CompositeUriComponentsContributor
httpRequestHandlerAdapter : class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter
simpleControllerHandlerAdapter : class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter
handlerExceptionResolver : class org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite
mvcViewResolver : class org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ViewResolverComposite
mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector : class org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration : class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da8643af
org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor : class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor
transactionAttributeSource : class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource
transactionInterceptor : class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor
org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory : class org.springframework.transaction.event.TransactionalEventListenerFactory
viewResolver : class org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver
myDataSource : class com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource
sessionFactory : class org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl
transactionManager : class org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager
org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator : class org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator
```

Answer (score 2):

`Environment` is a framework level bean which precise type and creation depends on the Spring components being used.

You are using Spring Web so it will most likely be `StandardServletEnvironment` bean created by [`GenericWebApplicationContext.createEnvironment()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/GenericWebApplicationContext.html#createEnvironment--) method. This should be called when the servlet is initialized by the servlet container. Other setups will do it differently e.g. Spring Boot will created `StandardEnvironment` bean in `SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment()` private method.

If you want to understand how it's created in your particular setup you need to debug your application startup.

Comment: Thank you Karol. Can you tell me why I cannot see this bean in the Spring container? I'm using applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames() and I cannot see the StandardServletEnvironment bean.

Comment: Not sure, maybe you are doing it too early in the lifecycle before `Environment` bean gets created or you have multiple application contexts? Start somewhere late in the lifecycle in the container, autowire `BeanFactory` and use `getBeansOfType(Environment.class)`